# Is it possible to control the the value computed in optimization to finite value?

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a function.m such that `function(x,y)` which is a continuous function for it is well-defined. For each `y` ranging from `0.04:0.02:0.2`, I want to find `x` such that `function(x,y)` gives value `0.5`. Unfortunately, `function(x,y)` is not defined for any `x`. For example, when `y=0.04`, `function(x,y)=0.4` when `x=2`, `function(x,y)=0.55` when `x=3`. It also gives that `function(x,y)=-inf` when `x<2`. On the other hand, when `y=0.05`, `function(x,y)=0.4` when `x=5`, `function(x,y)=0.81` when `x=9` and `function(x,y)=-inf` when `x<5`. I would like to use `fmincon` in matlab to solve the problem, so I write a loop to have me to find x

> y=0.04:0.02:0.2;
>
> for i=1:length(y)
>
> result=fmincon(@(x)abs(function(x,y(i))-0.5),2,[],[],[],[],[],[]);
>
> end

However, when doing optimization, it happens that, for example, when `y=0.04`, `x` is value chosen to be less than 2 and gives -inf value and cannot go further. I would like to know if it is possible to have setting that matlab can find finite values only, or when it tries a point which gives objective -inf, it can automatically find another x-value and continue the procedure.

I understand I could find particular range which gives value `0.5` for each `y` first, but it is very time consuming and I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
f = @(x, y)-y.*exp(x);
```

- The minimum value of f is `-inf`
- Target: Find `x` for which `f` has the smallest value but not `-inf`
- Constraint

```
-inf < f < inf --> f - inf < 0 and -f - inf < 0
```

- `inf` value approximation on matlab

```
>> exp(709) = 8.2184e+307
```

while

```
>> exp(710) = inf
```

I chose  `inf` to be `exp(709)`

Now I have a nonlinear constraint

```
f - exp(710) < 0 and -f - exp(710) < 0
```

Adding this to `fmincon()` `f` won't take infinite value

**Please read through the comments**

```
% Given y
y = 0.04:0.02:0.2;

% Given function f
f = @(x, y)-y.*exp(x);



% store fmincon solution x
x = zeros(size(y));

% store fminconfunction evaluation x
fval =zeros(size(y));
for i = 1:length(y)

    % function depending on x only
    g =@(x)f(x, y(i));

    % initial function evaluation constrained not to take infinite values
    c =  @(x)[g(x)-exp(709); -g(x)-exp(709)]; 
    ceq = @(x)[];
    constraints = @(k)deal(c(k),ceq(k));

    [x(i), fval(i)] = fmincon(g,2,[],[],[],[],[],[],constraints);
end
```

Output:

```
x = [76.6352  551.6941  702.1137   10.4739   13.6470  250.4344   22.4630   
28.4753  100.6441];

fval =  1.0e+303 *[-0.0000   -0.0000   -6.7174   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   
-0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000]
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. But note that in loop when i=1 and i=2, the domain are different. When i=1, lower bound of x is 2 but when i=2, lower bound of x is 5. It is impossible for me to find lower bound of x for each y if y has 10000 inputs. If I set the lower bound to be 2 for each loop, when i=2, it may test a value smaller than 5 and cannot continue. Should there any method to let matlab know that it should try another value, say 3 and next time 4 then 5 so that it can run?

Comment: @will_cheuk    Check the new update, you may change your code accordingly to this logic by including the `nonlinear constraint`